# Does android require all densities of a .webp file in resource folders?

Tags: android, webp

Does android requires all densities of a .webp file , same as like png files ?
I need to reduce Apk Size?

[image]

Any one please share your knowledge :)

Comment: No, but it helps with scaling

Comment: If you want to reduce the Apk size, you should switch to **Bundle**. That will generate multiple Apk files with the required resources for different devices. There will be no need to remove any resources. Also, if your app is not localised, you can remove the unused default android string by specifying it in the Gradle config.

Comment: @RishabhSagar, will Android App Bundle create images for mdpi, xhdpi, ...?